# Show emails to\from a contact in new Gmail?

Tags: gmail

In older version of gmail when you hover someones email it showed his\her badge that had "show all messages" link in it so you could quickly look through your previous exchanges with this person. Is there a way to do that now without typing email or copy-pasting it with a mouse into a search bar? Both of these ways are very slow.